# Selecting next two elements after clicking one. (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, traversal

I have a table like such:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr class='clickme'>
<td>...</td>
</tr>
<tr class='hidden1'>
<td>...</td>
</tr>
<tr class='hidden2'>
<td>...</td>
</tr>
<tr class='clickme'>
<td>...</td>
</tr>
<tr class='hidden1'>
<td>...</td>
</tr>
<tr class='hidden2'>
<td>...</td>
</tr>
[etc.]
</tbody>
</table>
```

.hidden1 and .hidden2 are display: none. My goal is to click on clickme and show the next two, but only those two, and only the ones "under" the clickme that I clicked.

I tried closest:

```
$('.clickme').click(function (e) {
    $(this).closest('.hidden1').remove();
    $(this).closest('.hidden2').remove();
});
```

No response. Multiple different things. I tried siblings with moderate success, but it only shows the first matches in the entire table. The table could have 100 of these  pairs.

```
$('.clickme').click(function (e) {
        $(this).siblings(".hidden1:first").toggle(); 
        $(this).siblings(".hidden2:first").toggle(); 
    });
```

I'm stumped, and I feel like it's such an easy solution!

Comment: `parent-div` where is that?

Comment: Like @Jai says, shouldn't it be: `$('.click-me').click(...` instead

Comment: .hide1 or .hide2 are not into your code

Comment: Just to clarify, `'.something'` is the jQuery selector for the element with the class name of `something`.

Comment: Sorry, updated with proper class names. Did a copy-paste and forgot to change the names for the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your markup it is easy to use `.nextUntil()`:

```
$(".clickme").click(function() {
    $(this).nextUntil(".clickme").toggle();
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/XEF2v/

If there could be other rows in between you can filter them with `.filter()`:

```
$(this).nextUntil(".clickme").filter(".hidden1, .hidden2").toggle();
```

Comment: +1 not what was explicitly required but probably the solution.

Comment: @dystroy `filter()` will do the job for any possible cases.

Comment: Not if there are other ".hidden1" between the two ".clickme".

Comment: @dystroy Then `.filter(".hidden1:first, .hidden2:first")`. Same easy: http://jsfiddle.net/XEF2v/1/.

Comment: Really good, I was using something similar, but without `toggle()`. Now, with `toggle()` I get rid of from `show` and `hide` ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you have other elements that you don't want to select before the following `".clickme"` and thus can't use VisioN's solution, you could  :

```
$('.clickme').click(function (e) {
    $(this).nextAll(".hide1").eq(0).toggle(); 
    $(this).nextAll(".hide2").eq(0).toggle(); 
});
```